# changes to allowsCameraControl (swift 4)?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a simple SCNScene with an object placed in the center (for example, a cube).  BEFORE the latest update to Swift 4, I enabled `allowsCameraControl` and the user could then rotate and manipulate (zoom in/out) the cube.  Now, (Swift 4, iOS 11) with the exact same code, when the user manipulates the cube, SOMETIMES the **direction** you swipe your finger matches the **direction** the cube moves, while other times, the direction you move your finger causes the cube to move the **opposite** direction!  It is NOT something that is always backwards or always correct, it can change as quickly as swiping one direction (correct cube movement), raising your finger, going back and trying to continue the same motion, but now the second swipe makes it rotate back the wrong way!

It almost seems like it's trying to use some specific point in the scene as a 'reference' of some kind.  Like if that point is on the front of the object, a swipe left makes it move left.  But if that point gets moved to the 'back' of the object, the next swipe left still moves the POINT left, but because it's in the 'back', moving left translates into the front of the object moving right. (with the same thing for up and down!)

Comment: It sounds just like moving objects in their local space after they are rotated, but then with allowsCameraControl you are not “moving” or “manipulating” the cube, you are rotating the camera. Take a look at the new cameraControlConfiguration options (for example in wwdc scenekit video).

Comment: @Xartec Thanks for the tip!  I watched the wwdc presentation and tried all the new 'defaultCameraController' options.  No matter what 'interactionMode' I try, the behavior I described originally doesn't change!  In fact, with some modes (arc and arcCentered) it gets noticeably worse!  I saw the demo in the video, the behavior they show is exactly what I'm trying to achieve but I'm using the new options that they do and it doesn't do the same thing!  Is it possible it's a gimble setting that's locking the camera into a certain orientation when it tries to move around the scene?